# the SBT native packager does not generate any sysv /etc/init.d/ script

Tags: playframework-2.0, sbt, sbt-native-packager

I am creating a debian package for a play 2.3.8 application.

I use the following settings:

```
 val settings = Seq(
   debianPackageDependencies in Debian := "openjdk-7-jre (>= 1.7.0)" :: Nil,
   maintainer in Linux := "team <support@dns.io>",
   packageSummary in Linux := "app",
   packageDescription := "description",
   serverLoading in Debian := ServerLoader.SystemV,
   linuxPackageMappings in Debian := linuxPackageMappings.value.map { p ⇒
     val newMappings = p.mappings.filterNot { f ⇒
       f._2.endsWith("conf//messages") ||
       f._2.endsWith("conf//play.plugins")
     }
     p.copy(mappings = newMappings)
   },
   daemonUser in Linux := (normalizedName in Debian).value
)
```

But no /etc/init.d/ script is generated.

If I remove the transformation of `linuxPackageMappings` then a init.d script is generated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `linuxPackageMappings in Debian := linuxPackageMappings.value...`, I used `linuxPackageMappings := linuxPackageMappings.value`.

And now it is working.

Comment: There are different files in different scopes. This is the core concept on which the sbt-native-packager works. In this solution you are filtering for _every_ linux distribution. In your answer you were using the general linux mappings to _override_ the linux+debian mappings.